# Codility - CountDiv JavaScript solution

Tags: javascript

I'm still a bit new to JavaScript so if anyone care to explain how to solve this small issue.

Basically, i'm using different languages to solve codility training tasks. I've encountered small problem when working with java script, floating points. Here is the example of what I mean. Task in question is in **Lesson 3**, [**task one: CountDiv**](https://codility.com/programmers/task/count_div)

In Java my solution works perfectly it scored 100/100. Here is the code:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {

        int offset = A % K ==0?1:0;

        return (B/K) - (A/K) + offset;

    }
}
```

Written in java script code scores 75/100.

```
function solution(A, B, K) {
   var offset;

   if (A % K === 0) {
       offset=1;
   } else {
       offset=0;
   }

   var result =(B/K) - (A/K) + offset;

   return parseInt(result);
}
```

JavaScript solution fails on following test:
A = 11, B = 345, K = 17
(Returns 19, Expects 20)

I'm assuming that its something to do with how JavaScript convert floating point to Integers ?

If anyone care to explain how to write JS solution properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `parseInt` on the division result.

When you use division operator, the result is coerced to floating point number, to make it integer use `parseInt` on it. (Thanks to [@ahmacleod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691511/ahmacleod))

```
function solution(A, B, K) {
    var offset = A % K === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    return parseInt(B / K) - parseInt(A / K) + offset;
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite correct. The issue is that `B/K` is integer division in java, but coerced to floating point division in javascript.

Comment: Sorry, rounding wont work. Even for initial input you will get wrong answer:
Using your code:
Example test:    [6, 11, 2] 
WRONG ANSWER  (got 4 expected 3)

Comment: @Bola It's working fine. Kindly check updated answer

Comment: Edit comment is correct, parseInt was the issue, thanks. Marking as answered.

Answer (score 3):

My first attempt was to make it this way:

```
function solution(A, B, K) {
    return Math.floor(B / K) - Math.floor(A / K) + (A % K === 0 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

and it scores 100/100,  as it was mentioned parseInt should do the trick as well.

Comment: I understand why we divide B and A by K and then take the difference (with 1 added). However I don't understand why we need to A % K and then sometimes not add 1? What is the rationale or intuition behind this? Is there an example?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032327/performance-issue-with-countdiv-codility-challenge-algorithm/62032609

Answer (score 0):

Swift 100%

```
public func solution(_ A : Int, _ B : Int, _ K : Int) -> Int {


    // write your code in Swift 4.2.1 (Linux)

     let offset = A % K == 0 ? 1 : 0

    return (B/K) - (A/K) + offset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(A, B, K) {
   return Math.floor(B / K) - Math.ceil(A / K) + 1;
}
```

Score 100/100

Answer (score 0):

```
    function solution(A, B, K) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
    let val;
    if(A % K === 0 || B % K === 0) {
        val = Math.floor(((B - A)/K + 1));
    } else {
        let x = A % K;
        let y = B % K;
        val = ((B - A) + (x - y))/K
    }
    if((B === A) && (B === K)) {
        val = Math.floor(((B - A)/K + 1));
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).