# Performance issue with CountDiv (Codility) challenge algorithm

Tags: java, performance, sorting, testing

Needing some help with the algorithm i made to solve this codility challenge :

*Write a function that, given three integers A, B and K, returns the number of integers within the range [A..B] that are divisible by K. 
For example, for A = 6, B = 11 and K = 2, your function should return 3, because there are three numbers divisible by 2 within the range [6..11], namely 6, 8 and 10.

A and B are integers within the range [0..2,000,000,000];
K is an integer within the range [1..2,000,000,000];
A ≤ B.*

```
public class Solution {
        public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {

            int counter = 0;
            ArrayList<Integer> listOfNumbersInBetween = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = A; i <= B; i++) {
                listOfNumbersInBetween.add(i);
            }

            for (int arrayElement : listOfNumbersInBetween) {
                if (arrayElement % K == 0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            return counter;

        }}
```

As you can see, my solution works perfectly but performance wise it's scoring 0% due to the time complexity O(B-A).

How can i improve this code to make it score 100%?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a loop is brute-force, and challenges like this cannot be done with brute-force.

Which means you have to **calculate** the result. Challenges like this are more often a *math* question more than a *programming* question, so put you math hat on.

So think about it. In a range of integers, *calculate* how many are divisible by K. If I asked you to do this manually *(using a simple calculator is allowed)*, without using a computer to brute-force it, how would you doing it? E.g. find how many integers between `111` and `999` that are divisible by `13`

*Hint*

Find the first number in the range that is divisible by K, and the last number in the range that is divisible by K. For the example above, that would be `117` and `988`.

Now calculate how many integers are divisible by K from first to last integer, remembering to count both of them. So, how many integers between `117` and `988` are divisible by `13`?

> Answer: (988 - 117) / 13 + 1 = 871 / 13 + 1 = 67 + 1 = **68**

Comment: Why do we need to add `1` to the result? And what happens if we take `988 - 111` instead?

Comment: @CyberMew Because: *"remembering to count both of them"* --- E.g. even numbers between 16 and 20, both inclusive: (20 - 16) / 2 = 4 / 2 = 2, then +1 because both numbers are inclusive, so total is 3 (16, 18, 20).

Comment: Appreciate the fast response! Understood. But seems like if, for example we get numbers between 1 and 3, and if we divide by say 5, we should get total of 0, and in another example between 5 and 5, and we divide by 5, I think we should get total of 1. I will try to test this out, thanks!

Comment: @CyberMew If you divide by 5, i.e. have K=5, then (according to the instructions in the answer in the paragraph starting with "Find ...") when you *normalize* the min-max values of 1-3, you get 5-0, so there are no value between those: result=0.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the normalise of values 1-3 to get 5-0?

Comment: @CyberMew If you need to find numbers in range 5-25 that are divisible by 6, we first normalize the boundaries to themselves be divisible by 6. First such number >=5 is 6, and last such number <=25 is 24, so the normalized range is 6-24. We then calculate (24 - 6) / 6 + 1 = 18 / 6 + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4, so there are 4 numbers in the given 5-25 range: 6, 12, 18, 24. --- If the range had been 14-16, then normalized range is 18-12, and since that's an inverted range, the result is 0, i.e. there are no numbers in range 14-16 that is divisible by 6.

Comment: Brilliant solution.  But as is always the case in Codility World, the trouble is in the edge cases. . . especially 0.  I'm getting the error "...for the input [0, 0, 11] the solution returned a wrong answer (got 0 expected 1)."  Meaning that 0 mod 11 is somehow supposed to be counted.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to take advantage of integer arithmetic to get rid of some edge cases.  Sometimes `A` and `B` are both, neither, or one or the other is divisible by `k`.  And just subtracting them won't really help solve the problem. So one solution is to divide each by `k` before subtracting them.

Say `k = 7, A = 12, and B = 54`.
`54/7 - 12/7 = 7 - 1 = 6  (14,21,28,35,42,49)`

But what if `A` was `14`?

`54/7 - 14/7 = 7 - 2 = 5  (14,21,28,35,42,49)`  The answer is one off. So when `A` is divisible by `k`, `1` needs to be added.

What if `A` and `B` are both divisible by `k`?

`56/7 - 14/7 = 8 - 2 = 6 = (14,21,28,34,42,49,56)`.  The answer is again, one off, so the special case of `A` being divisible by `k` takes care of it by adding `1`

```
int result = (B/k - A/k) + ((A%k == 0) ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

My C# solution, based on @Andreas' brilliant one.  This eventually got me to 100%.  Most surprising (and perhaps wrong?) is that [0, 0, 11] needs to produce a result of 1, meaning that 0 is considered divisible by 11.  You'll see I had to comment out an error catcher to allow B to be zero and get me to the "expected" answer.  I was surprised that (0-0)/11 didn't produce a runtime error, but it didn't.

```
    public int solutionCountDiv4(int A, int B, int K)
    {
        //Errors
        if (K == 0)
            return 0;

        //if (B == 0)
        //    return 0;

        if (A > B)
            return 0;

        var first = 0;
        var last = 0;

        for (first = A; first <= B; first++)
        {
            if (first % K == 0)
                break;
        }
        for (last = B; last >= A; last--)
        {
            if (last % K == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (first > last)
            return 0;

        var result = (last - first) / K + 1;
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Small correction to @[Ersin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72296476/7759044)

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K)
{
  auto result =  B / K - (A - 1) / K;
  if (A == 0 and K > 1)
    result++;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: If this is just a correction, then suggest an edit instead.

Comment: StackOverflow refused me an edit :-(

Comment: ok. then please at least [edit] your post to describe in words _what_ you corrected so that it's immediately obvious.